# How is this subclass implicitly calling the constructor of its parent class?

Tags: java

I have these two classes:

```
public class Document {
    private static int quantity = 0;
    public Document() {
        quantity = quantity + 1;
    }
    public static int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
}

public class Book extends Document {
    private int numChapters;
    public Book(int numChapters) {
        this.numChapters = numChapters;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b1 = new Book(4);
        Book b2 = new Book(6);
        Document d1 = new Document();
        System.out.println(Document.getQuantity());
    }
}
```

The program here returns 3, but I expect it to return 1. Can someone tell me what is happening in the code? It seems that the parent class's constructor is being implicitly called when b1 and b2 are created. From what I understand, subclasses don't inherit the constructor of their parent class.

Comment: It is implicitly called.

Comment: So do all objects of a subclasses implicitly the constructor of their parent class or is this a special case? Why is it being implicitly called?

Comment: If the superclass constructor wasn't called, the superclass parts of the object wouldn't be constructed, and you'd have an unusable object.

Comment: For you to be born, you first need your parents to be born.
Since the parent is static every time you create a new Book, the quantity will be incremented.

Answer (score 5):

See the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html):

> Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass
>   constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the
>   no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not
>   have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error.
>   Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only
>   superclass, there is no problem.

You have a no-argument constructor which is automatically called.

This behavior makes sense, constructors are meant to create objects. So it should contain proper initialization code for its class. What if you your class extends another one? Shouldn't it contain all the code needed to construct that object?

Answer (score 0):

sub-classes must call a constructor of their super class, even if the sub-class's constructors don't explicitly call `super()`. In fact, if the compiler can't find a super-class's constructor that it can call from the sub-class's constructor, the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that the parent class's constructor is being implicitly called when b1 and b2 are created.

That is correct.

> From what I understand, subclasses don't inherit the constructor of their parent class.

That is also correct.  However, it does NOT mean that the superclass constructor is not called.

In Java, when an object is created<sup>1</sup> using `new` (or the reflective equivalent) a superclass constructor is always called, whether or not you have a `super(...)` call in the subclass constructor.

---

<sup>1 - For the record, when an instance is created by object deserialization, no constructors are called.  The recreation of the object is done by some behind-the-curtains black magic that makes the object without calling its constructor.</sup>